# Tournament schedule with five teams each play the other teams once and two pitches available

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

Five teams play in a tournament, each playing the other four teams once. If two pitches are available, how many periods are needed to schedule all the matches?

I labelled the five teams, $A,B,C,D,E$. Each team represents a vertex of the $K_5$ complete graph. The number of edges is $10$, which means for each team to play the other four teams once, there need to be 10 matches in total. What I don't understand is the two pitches, how do the two pitches affect the number of periods needed to schedule the matches?

Comment: If only one pitch were available, wouldn't it take ten periods to play all ten games? With two pitches, maybe you can save some time by scheduling two games at the same time?

Comment: 5 periods...A plays 4 matches with other..B 3....C 2...D 1>>>so 10 matches ...But 2 pitches gives 5 periods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To schedule a tournament for $n$ teams with $k$ pitches available, you must assign periods to the matches such that

1. no team is scheduled to play more than one match in a period, and
2. no period has more than $k$ matches scheduled (since otherwise there isn't room to play all those matches at once).

So you need an edge-colouring of $K_n$ where no colour is used more than $k$ times. The minimum number of colours to do this is the number of periods needed.

In this case, two pitches is enough that you don't have to worry about (2), since if you had three matches scheduled for the same period, you would have some team involved in more than one of them, so (1) wouldn't be satisfied either. So here the answer is just the chromatic index of $K_5$.